# 400 bad request for reply to message microsoft graph reply to message in teams channel

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-logic-apps, azure-service-principal

I'm trying to use Reply to message API for Graph api I have a service principle that has these rights [image]

so what to use this SP to send reply to message from logic app
I read that using sp is only possible with Migrate.All access rights which i can not get how then this sp with delegated rights can be used to send this message using Graph API in automated way from logic app

Comment: The easiest way is to use a named user. Create a service account and do it that way IF you want to stay away from your own username.

Comment: and how can I get a bearer token for my user in an automatic way not with manual consent from user? to use then this bearer token when calling Graph API

Answer (score 0):

I have granted `ChannelMessage.Send` permission.

[image]

I have used the below URL to create the code which I am going to use for generating bearer token.

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
&client_id={client_id}
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms
&response_mode=query
&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
&state=12345
```

Copied the code.

[image]

Generating the bearer token as shown below.

[image]

Sending reply to Teams channel in logic app as given below.

**URL**-

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams/{team-id}/channels/{channel-id}/messages/{message-id}/replies
```

[image]

**Response**-

[image]

[image]

Comment: @nkol In step 1, User Authorization is required to generate the code as this is Authorization Code grant flow. So 1st step is only invoked from the browser but you can integrate the 2nd step in logic app

Comment: how long is valid this first code? that is used for getting token can i once genereted use unlimited to obatian token from login app

Comment: @nkol If you are using the same bearer token then its fine. If you are generating new bearer token every time then you need new code also.

Comment: Refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60602774/authorization-request-to-get-access-on-behalf-of-a-user-results-in-a-cookiesdis

Comment: but if generate this once the auth code is valid 10min and baerer 1h so  I can not use it in logic app then :( is there some way to make this possible from logic app?

Comment: If you intend to use delegate permission type then you have to generate token using Authorization code grant flow only. Are you willing to use Application permission type like **Teamwork.Migrate.All**?

Comment: no since this is very high rights and there is security risk so not allowed to use this permission do not get it why such high permission is used on app level for this api :(

Comment: @nkol If you would like to use end to end flow in logic app then you need to use application level permission wherein you can have client_credential grant type during generating token